# Lie algebra and orthogonal basis at every point

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Hello Lie group experts,

Is it possible to guarantee that we could always find a set of right invariant vector fields spanning a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and pair-wise orthogonal to each other at every point $g \in G$?

Comment: What does "orthogonal" mean here? You need to pick a Riemannian metric on $G$ to make sense of this; what condition do you want on this metric?

Comment: Yes. It is assumed to be a Riemannian manifold equipped with a metric   that defines the manifold itself. Suppose $\left\{v_1,\dotsc,v_r\right\}$ span $\mathfrak{g}$. Then, is it always possible: $v_i\vert_g \perp v_j\vert_g,\,\; \forall\, i \neq j$, $\forall\, g \in G$ and $v_i\vert_g,\; v_j\vert_g \in TG\vert_g$ w.r.t. that metric.

Comment: Non-expert here. Right invariance and orthogonality is equivalent to the metric itself being right invariant.

Comment: True. However, my point is that if we can  **ALWAYS** find a set of right invariant vector fields spanning Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, s.t. they induce a bi-invariant Riemannian metric on $G$? If so, how can we prove or disprove it? For instance, if $G$ is semisimple, then Killing form defines a bi-invariant metric using adjoint representations of basis vector fields and under this metric, basis vectors are pair-wise orthogonal.

Comment: @iliTheFallen Not every Lie group admits a bi-invariant metric.

Comment: Check out Exercise 1.6.25 in Petersen's Riemannian Geometry 2016, as Kajelad says, a biinvariant metric is a strong condition that does not follow from the Lie group structure.

Comment: Oh I see. Ok @Laz. Let me check out that Exercise and see if a bell rings :)